# Call C# from Js in WebView - Xamarin.Forms (iOS and Android)

Tags: javascript, xamarin, webview

I need a way to do c# calls to save some data (coming from js function in a webview) in my sqLite.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that this won't be directly possible in Xamarin.Forms. You will probably need to write a custom renderer for each platform. Here is an article on custom renderers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/. You will probably need to write one for the WebView class. Once you've done so, you'll be able to get at the native control and use its underlying functionality. I recommend trying the UWP one first as that will be the most straight forward.

This article explains how to intercept a JavaScript alert in UWP
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-intercept-854d33da

But, you will also need to give more detail about what you actually want to do. What data do you want to pass back?